# WYSIWYG HTML/CSS editor which can generate div, float, padding

Tags: html, css, wysiwyg

Say, I want to align 4 images in a single row, with spacing among each images according to my preference. Most of the time, I have to achieve this by hand coded HTML/CSS using div, float, padding...

I try to speed up my development process, by trying several WYSIWYG editor like http://ckeditor.com/, http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/...

None of them able to achieve this, without the need of hand code.

I was wondering, in current market, is there any WYSIWYG HTML/CSS editor which can generate div, float, padding...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems a bit custom for a WYSIWYG editor. I would try to write a simple plugin for TinyMCE. They don't need to be very complicated:

http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?atid=738747&group_id=103281&func=browse

Comment: It seems there are no such smart WYSIWYG editor in current market.

Answer (score 0):

I was recently turned on to [WYMEditor](http://www.wymeditor.org/), which is a What You *Mean* Is What You Get editor. It generates very semantic markup and allows you to create custom styles/classes that can be applied for exactly that kind of case. Have a look at their demos and check it out for yourself.

Comment: I really like WYMeditor myself, but I don't think it addresses @YanChengCheok's problem.

Comment: He would have to write the styles for the class once, but then it'd be set for him or anyone else using it afterward. It's gonna do that more effectively than any WYSIWYG editor I've tried...